# PYTHON: concating values if similar values found in a dictonary

Tags: python, list, concatenation

PYTHON:
I have a Dictionary as:

```
abc = {[
    ["buy", "contract_type"], ["apple", "product"], ["from", "o"],
    ["Alex", "trader_name"], ["heeb", "trader_name"], ["of", "o"],
    ["APPLE", "counter_party"], ["INC", "counter_party"]]}
```

What I want is,
basically concatinating values for similar keys in a dictonary

```
new_abc = {[
    ["buy", "contract_type"], ["apple", "product"], ["from", "o"],
    ["Alex heeb", "trader_name"], ["of", "o"],
    ["APPLE INC", "counter_party"]]}
```

Comment: Thats a list, not a dictionary, what have you tried?

Comment: I think you want to group the first elements by their associated second element, then concatenate the found first elements and re-associate them with their second element.

Comment: @Alfe - That wouldn't explain why `from` and `of` remain seperate

Comment: @Sayse Exactly.  That's why I ask for clarification.  I guess not combining these is just an error OP made when paper-computing the result.

Comment: Your edit just made it a set instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {}
for a, b in abc:
    d.setdefault(b, []).append(a)
new_abc = [ [ ' '.join(d.pop(b)), b ] for a, b in abc if b in d ]
```

But as @Sayse already pointed out, this will also combine the `'o'` values `'from'` and `'of'`:

```
[['buy', 'contract_type'], ['apple', 'product'], ['from of', 'o'],
 ['Alex heeb', 'trader_name'], ['APPLE INC', 'counter_party']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby    

abc = [
["buy", "contract_type"], ["apple", "product"], ["from", "o"],
["Alex", "trader_name"], ["heeb", "trader_name"], ["of", "o"],
["APPLE", "counter_party"], ["INC", "counter_party"]]

new= [] 
for k, g in groupby(sorted(abc, key=lambda x:x[1]),key =lambda x:x[1]): 
    new.append(['',k]) 
    for i in g: 
        new[-1][0] += i[0]+ ' '
```

`new` will be your expected output:

```
[['buy ', 'contract_type'],
 ['APPLE INC ', 'counter_party'],
 ['from of ', 'o'],
 ['apple ', 'product'],
 ['Alex heeb ', 'trader_name']]
```

Comment: This adds spaces to each first element.  Also it messes up the original order of the items.  No idea if either is relevant, but it's at least worth mentioning.